# Wrap an image/pattern inside Text

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to achieve this effect in HTML/CSS.

[image]

I know gradients work, but this exact patter is impossible to create with gradients.

Has anyone have some solution or this is just simply impossible to create inHTML/CSS? 
In a last resort i'll use an image unfortunately.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/) goes over how to achieve this with graceful fallbacks on browsers that don't support it. This is the CSS to achieve it on browsers that support webkit.

```
h1 {
   color: fallbackColor;
   background: url(path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```